# Can I create a Hashcode without zeros or letter 'O'?

Tags: database, pandas, pyspark, hashcode

I am using pyspark's sha1() functions to generate the hashcode, is there a way to avoid zeros and alphabet 'O' in the hashcode? I using the hashcode to generate unique 6 character key for my data. I need it to be hash, as when something changes in data I need a new hashcode and new 6 character key. the only problem is when I substring 6 characters from the hash, leading zero gets omited when the data is exported to CSV. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Just call sha1(), then replace every zero with a G and every Oh with an H

Answer (score 0):

Adding to JoelFan's -

Use regex_replace as below

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
newDf = df.withColumn('new_column_name', regexp_replace('column_name', 'character_to_replace', 'with_this'))
```